# Loop to create multiple rows with different names in excel using Apache PoI

Tags: java, apache-poi

As it stands right now I have 241 lines of code used to created 46 rows and populate the first column of each row in excel using HSSFRow. Each row is named so I can reference it later on to add more columns to that particular row.

I am trying to create a loop that will create these row's for me and save me 200+ lines of code which is just plain boring to read over. Is there anyway to dynamically name and create rows using loops?

Here is a chunk of my code that works just fine but is repeated an insane amount. The only difference between the blocks(Besides the index which is easy to loop over and change) are the variable names that I put a ** by:

```
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("Ions");

    HSSFRow **name = worksheet.createRow((short) 0);
        HSSFCell **cellA1 = **name.createCell((short) 0);
        **cellA1.setCellValue("Name: ");



    HSSFRow **lot = worksheet.createRow((short) 1);
        HSSFCell **cellA2 = **lot.createCell((short) 0);
        **cellA2.setCellValue("Lot #: ");


       //..... This is done 46 more times!
```

I have created some arrays that hold the strings that I want to be the variable names but cannot figure out how to implement this if it is even possible. So far this is what I was thinking, it doesn't work but shows the idea I am trying to get to:

```
String[] nameString = {"name", "lot",...etc};

String[] cells = new String[50];//cellA1-A46
            for(int i=0; i<46; i++){
                cells[i] = "cellA"+(i+1);
                System.out.print(cells[i] + ", ");
            }

String[] text = {"Name: ", "Lot #: ",...etc};


for(int i = 0; i < 46; i++){
  //creates row named from the index of nameString[].
HSSFRow nameString[i] = worksheet.createRow((short) i);
       //creates cell named from index of cells[].
    HSSFCell cells[i] = nameString[i].createCell((short) 0);
      //sets that created cell equal to the index of text[]
    cells[i].setCellValue(text[i]);
```

If anyone has any ideas please share! 
Thanks! -pdatric

Comment: Why do you need simultaneous references to all of the cells that you create? Once you're done with a cell, reuse that variable for the next cell. If you need to revisit a cell, you can always access it from the workbook--no need to maintain your own variables or arrays.

Comment: You know I never did think about it like that. I am already getting the each cell later in my program before I add to it, and am essentially creating the same variable twice.

You just saved me a ton of code! Thank you IceArdor.